# Submit for Approval Url formula

Tags: apex, approval-process

My ultimate solution would be to have a formula field that can call the submit action for a given record so that I could kick off an approval process from a related list for the object.  Basically I would like to use `{!URLFOR( $Action.sObject__c.Submit, sObject__c.ID )}` in a formula field.  However that doesn't work because you can't reference $actions from a formula.

My next thought was to create a custom list button with check boxes so that each item in the related list could be selected and then I could call

```
{!URLFOR( $Action.sObject.Submit, {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.sObject__c)} )}
```

But that doesn't work either. Probably can't pass in a list of id's. I would like to avoid calling a webservice to process the approvals if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by 'avoid calling a webservice'? Do you want to stay away from APEX? Because that's what will be needed for this functionality..

Comment: In this [document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_action_values.htm&type=0) it says "**All objects support basic actions, such as new, clone, view, edit, list, and delete. The $Action global also references actions available on many standard objects.**" I don't think to can use $Actelion for approval on custom objects